# Syntax for NgClass if/else with string

Tags: angular, ternary-operator, angular2-nativescript

I've been trying to do something very simple:

I've got a variable in my component called `sortedBySize`. `sortedBySize` can either equal `""` (empty), `"asc"` or `"desc"`.

in my HTML I'm trying to make a conditional NgClass statement. I've tried many different ways but I can never get it to work. Here's my syntax:

```
<Label ng-class="{ sortSelected: sortedBySize === '', sortNotSelected: sortedBySize !== '' }" style="margin-left:1;" class="text-center" width="33%" [text]="'Not sorted'" (tap)="somefunction()"></Label>
<Label ng-class="{ sortSelected: sortedBySize === 'asc', sortNotSelected: sortedBySize !== 'asc' }" style="margin-left:1;" class="text-center" width="33%" [text]="'Asc'" (tap)="somefunction()"></Label>
<Label ng-class="{ sortSelected: sortedBySize === 'desc', sortNotSelected: sortedBySize !== 'desc' }" style="margin-left:1;" class="text-center" width="33%" [text]="'Desc'" (tap)="someFunction()"></Label>
```

for good measure, my css:

```
.sortSelected {
  background-color: green;
}

.sortNotSelected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

I've changed up the ternary statement in as many ways I could think of, but it's just not working and I don't know why. The classes work fine when statically added to the regular `class`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried [ngClass] instead of ng-class ?

Comment: `style="margin-left:1;"` won't do anything without a unit

Comment: @JeremyThille Firstly, that wasn't the problem. Second, I just confirmed that it certainly does something. -- IE set a margin to the left, ;)

Comment: That wasn't the main problem, that's why my comment was just a comment, not an answer. And IE doing IE things is irrelevant :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
<Label [ngClass]="{ 'sortSelected': sortedBySize === '', 'sortNotSelected': sortedBySize !== '' }" 
       style="margin-left:1;" 
       class="text-center" 
       width="33%" 
       [text]="'Not sorted'" 
       (tap)="somefunction()">
</Label>
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been at this for hours, finally got it right. Will accept the answer as soon as possible.

Comment: You're wellcome guy! :D